# Is it good practice to use magic numbers?

Tags: html, sql, language-agnostic, coding-style

I am making a web app. In certain cases in server side I am making mysql queries where I basically say `where d.id=2` meaning I hard-code a foreign key to another table. Or in client side, I have a form with a radio field, and the input field values are the id numbers (ex. 1, 2, 3) of primary keys to a table.

I want to know is using these 'magic numbers' good practice, or should I instead use the string values in the queries (would require a join) and in the forms as the input values, where I would then need to get the id using that string value using a query.

It seems both ways, if I need to edit the table rows (changing primary key value or string value), then I would have to update everything in client and server side.

What is the good practice?

Thanks

Comment: For your question about the form, I prefer to display the text and submit the id field.

Comment: Can you show an example, I don't get you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID numbers are generally assigned arbitrarily by the database (e.g. with MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT`), and they're just accidents of timing. It's generally a bad idea to depend on them and hard-code them into your code. The corresponding name is less likely to change, so if you have to hard-code something, that's usually safer.

Also, hard-coding IDs makes the code harder to understand. Magic numbers have no inherent meaning to the reader, but strings are mnemonic.

Comment: That seems like the right answer, but my logic is like, say you use the string values everywhere, and then you decide to change the string value of the record in the db, then you have to update it everywhere. For example, 'red' to 'green'. I can picture this happening, but cannot see when an id would change. Can you explain why id values are more likely to change?

Comment: If you need to recreate the database, strings won't change but IDs might.

Comment: But if you recreate the database, you could just easily add the id attribute, and force it to be the same though? Like even if its auto increment, you could still add the id value and as long is its currently unique, it would work.

Comment: Yes, you could, but that's an extra detail you shouldn't have to concern yourself with. IDs shouldn't have any special meaning by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is a formatted comment.  Since omega requested an example, here is one using ColdFusion syntax

```
<cfquery name="getChoices">
select choiceId, choice
from choices
</cfquery>

<form>
<cfoutput query = "getChoices">
<input type = "radio" name="theChoice" value = "#choiceID#">#choice#
</cfoutput>
<input type="submit>
</form>
```

Note that the cfoutput tag loops through the query results.